# Git: Unmodified file generates pathspec error

Tags: git

I first noticed this problem while trying to `git restore *` a few files.

Given the `git status` result:

```
On branch myBranch
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   path/myFile.txt
    modified:   path/myFile2.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

When I try to `git restore *` or `git checkout *` I get the following message:

```
error: pathspec 'unknownFile.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

where `unknownFile.txt` is a file I recognize from my project and which I don't recall having edited recently (though I may be mistaken, as it's a fairly complex project). I am sure its path hasn't changed (no parent folders were renamed).

As you can see, this file doesn't get listed as changed when I enter `git status` but is still in the way somehow.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I may find out why this file keeps trying to update?

ETA: I forgot to add that checking for `git status -u` does not return any additional files.

Comment: It's an untracked file, and you're using a shell that expands `*` (e.g., bash or zsh). So you asked Git to `git restore unknownFile.txt`, which it does not know how to do.

Comment: I forgot to add this in the original question, but unknownFile.txt isn't listed as an untracked file either.

Comment: @attraverso It's most probably ignored. Try `git check-ignore -v unknownFile.txt`

Comment: @phd huh. Apparently it is. Any idea on why git might be suddenly generating an error on an ignored file, though?

Comment: @attraverso Ignored files are ignored for `git status` and `git add`. But if you list it in another command like `git checkout` GIt reports an error because it doesn't know how to checkout a file it doesn't track.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66853238/git-unmodified-file-generates-pathspec-error#comment118173908_66853238), here is why (and when) you get the error:

1. Your *shell* is expanding the `*`.
2. The file exists in your working tree.
3. The file *does not exist* in Git's index and the current commit.

Item 3—the fact that the file *isn't* in Git's index and *isn't* in the current commit—is why *Git* says:

> ```
> error: pathspec 'unknownFile.txt' did not match any file(s) known to git
> ```

As [phd noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66853238/git-unmodified-file-generates-pathspec-error#comment118174529_66853238), an untracked file can be "ignored."<sup>1</sup>  That's why it does not show up in `git status` either.  If `git status` says nothing about a file, you know one of two things: either it's *tracked and not changed*, or it is *not tracked and the normal `git status` complaint about being untracked is suppressed*, probably via `.gitignore`.

Item 2—the fact that the file does exist—is obvious, because you see it.

Item 1—the fact that it is your *shell* that is expanding the `*` to all file names—is a bit of a subtle point.  Unix-style shells (sh, bash, zsh, and so on) don't depend on file-name-expansion being built into every *command*.  When you run:

```
command *
```

here, the *shell* notices the `*`, says to itself: *ah, you mean I should list all the files and directory names here, and pass those names to `command`*, and does exactly that.

Other command line interpreters, notably CMD.EXE on DOS/Windows, *don't* treat `*` specially.  Running `command *` just runs the command with one argument, a literal asterisk `*`.  If you do pass a literal asterisk to various Git commands, many of them take that to mean: *figure out which files this applies to*.

When *Git* does the figuring, it uses the files currently in Git's index (`git checkout *`) or in the current commit (`git restore *`) and you will not see any errors here.  You can get this effect with a Unix-style shell by *quoting* the asterisk:

```
git restore "*"
```

or:

```
git restore \*
```

or:

```
git restore '*'
```

(all three do the same thing for this particular case; the different quoting styles are for different purposes).

---

<sup>1</sup>`.gitignore` is the wrong name, as file names or patterns in this file are not files that are *ignored*.  The problem is that a technically-correct name might read something like `.git-do-not-complain-about-these-file-names-when-they-are-untracked-files-and-do-not-automatically-add-them-with-en-masse-add-operations`, and that would be ridiculous, so the shorthand name `.gitignore` is used.

Comment: Cool, this is first I’ve heard about quoting to get Git to do the globbing. Can you say more about the three styles?

Comment: @matt: double quotes protect against globbing, but not against variable expansion: `"*${foo}*"` expands the `$foo` part but leaves the two asterisks untouched. Single quotes protect against both so that `'*${foo}*'` is just those characters, literally. Backslash quotes the *next character only*, so, for instance, if you want to print "isn't" you can use `echo isn\'t`; if you need a dollar sign as well, consider `echo '$isn'\'t`, for instance.

Comment: (Of course `echo \$isn\'t` also works and is fine. The backslash-for-single-quote trick is useful in cheesy quote-stuff-for-the-shell algorithms: start with a single quote, exit it and emit backslash singlequote for single quote, and then resume single quotes. Close the whole thing with a final single quote.)

Comment: sadly I cannot say I tested your solution since a colleague came and had me `git restore .` to get rid of the problem (and given I'm not clear on how I got in that situation in the first place, I don't know how to replicate it)

Comment: @attraverso: that also works (and avoids quoting issues). Not all programs handle this the same way as Git so it's good to understand which part of what system is doing what with which parts of your command line, though. If you want to repeat the problem, take any repository in which `git restore *` is OK to run at the moment (e.g., a fresh but temporary clone), create in it one untracked file ("echo foo > new-foo-file"), and try `git restore *`.